# ImageMagick: inter-line spacing with captions creates cutoff's

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using the following command to create a caption. But I want to control the interline spacing as well. When I set the value to negative (to get the lines closer to eachother), the first line gets it's capital letters cut off. I tried added a "border", but that just adds a border - doesn't add "padding". Is there a way to add "padding"?

```
convert templates/input.pdf -font test.ttf 
-size 1245x283! -background red -fill white -gravity northwest 
-interline-spacing -25 
caption:"Interline-Spacing NOT WORKING\r\nwith Captions" 
-geometry +129+129 -composite output/temp.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, you can set the -gravity center, then use -trim +repage, if you want to remove excess around the text and then add any amount of border back using -border or -extent if you know the desired output size.

Try this using unix syntax:

```
convert \( -size 2115x560 xc:skyblue \) \( -size 1245x283! -background red -fill white -gravity center -font arial -interline-spacing -25 caption:"Interline-Spacing NOT WORKING\r\nwith Captions" -trim +repage -background red -extent 1245x283! \) -gravity northwest -geometry +129+129 -composite temp.png
```

or this in Windows:

```
convert ( -size 2115x560 xc:skyblue ) ( -size 1245x283! -background red -fill white -gravity center -font arial -interline-spacing -25 caption:"Interline-Spacing NOT WORKING\r\nwith Captions" -trim +repage -background red -extent 1245x283! ) -gravity northwest -geometry +129+129 -composite temp.png
```

[image]

If you want the white text left justified, then use -gravity west before -extent and -gravity west before the caption:

```
convert \( -size 2115x560 xc:skyblue \) \( -size 1245x283! -background red -fill white -gravity west -font arial -interline-spacing -25 caption:"Interline-Spacing NOT WORKING\r\nwith Captions" -trim +repage -background red -gravity west -extent 1245x283! \) -gravity northwest -geometry +129+129 -composite temp2.png
```

[image]

Replace your input image in place of my -size 2115x560 xc:skyblue and your font for mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the interline spacing is from the base line of the text up. Lower letters will protrude below the base line. I suppose it is more of a "line height"

The obvious solution is to either increase the spacing to allow for capital letters or do not use capital letters.

A setting of -15 seems to work for what you are doing.